# How to get pixel coordinates as latlng from a jpg image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, projection, map-projections, mercator

I have a map image as jpg format. I am trying to calculate latitude and longitude for each pixel. I have 3 points coordinate also pixel row and column.

At first actually I used python utm library and calculated distance difference between two points by using lat and lng. I used:
diff_meters_x / diff_pixels_x
diff_meters_y / diff_pixels_y
After I found one pixel difference in x-axis and y-axis, I tried to test with third point but it shows a different point nearly 100 km tolerated but pixels and lat lngs are correct.

Then I tried to use gdal library but it calculates .tif extension images. I am using python 2.7 but if there is another way, also I can you use another platform like matlab. Could you help me about the way to figure this problem out?

[Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNhAT.jpg)

Here are three points:

BLK:
LatLng: 39.760751, 27.840443 || UTM_Meters: 571990.1817772812, 4401541.17886532 || Zone/Band: 35, 'S' || Pixel: [210, 247]

KUT:
LatLng: 39.495730, 29.997087 || UTM_Meters: 757725.0341605131, 4376079.988600584 || UTM_Zone/Band: 35, 'S' || Pixel: [288, 260]

USAK:
LatLng: 38.754252, 29.337908 || UTM_Meters: 703154.2913673887, 4292101.594408637 ||  UTM_Zone/Band: 35, 'S' || Pixel: [265, 296]

Answer (score 0):

Ttake a look at the basemap python package from matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html

Lat/long calculation heavily depend on the projection of the picture and basemap does this for you.

Comment: I tried this way, basemap just creates a new map, it's not projecting like google maps getProject. Unfortunately it didnt go with this.